# Pint all the odd numbers between 2 numbers using pointer and array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I don't know what's wrong with the code but segmentation fault is coming up.

If l=2 and k= 5 then output should be 3 5

```
#include<stdio.h>
int* odd(int,int,int*);
int main()   
{
    int l,k,*count;
    int o;
    o=0;
    printf("enter l and k");\\entering the lest and right limit\\
    scanf("%d%d",&l,&k);
    count= odd(l,k,&o);\\passing address of o so i can get the count of 
                         loop using pointer\\
    for(int j=0;j<=(o);j++)
    printf("%d",*(count +j));
}
int* odd(int l,int k,int * o)
{
    int t[10],m=0;

    for(int i=l;i<=k;i++)
    {
    if(i/2!=0)
    {
    t[m]=i;
    m++;
    }
    }
    *o=m;(using pointer to get count of loop)
    return(&t[0]);
}
```

Comment: Look up "how to return an array from a function in C".

Comment: Also remember to tag the question with your language name (in this case [tag:c]), and version if needed ([c11] for example)

Comment: The code in the question cannot possibly be the code you're running!

Comment: \\ this is not single line comments notation. It should be `//`

Answer (score 1):

By doing this

```
return(&t[0]); /* here you are returning address of locally created array, its scope is within this function only */
```

your program causing **undefined behavior** as you are *returning address of locally created array variable* from a function, since its scope is within this function not outside. Your compiler should have warn you like this

> error: function returns address of local variable
>   [-Werror=return-local-addr]

if you could have compiled with flags like

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror test.c
```

Comment: So i have to create dynamic memory to pass the array?

Comment: yes you can do it by creating dynamic array & returning it to `main()` and free the dynamic pointer once usage is done. Another way is to pass the buffer & its length in the function argument itself for e.g `odd(l,k,t, numOfEle);`